tag "alternatives" losing focus
I thing the tag alternatives is now losing focus, now that we have established that currencies so different from Bitcoin such as Ripple are IT.
We should either define precisely what is that tag about, or abolish it.
I hope nobody expects to tag that way all non-bitcoin questions, because it would be inconsistent with the enlarged scope of this site.
edit: either I get some answer to this question, or I'll consider going on and manually removing it one by one...
edit: deleted them again. Stack is failing. Either stop re-adding it, or answer here! It would be better if the mods just banned the tag, of course.
Fuck, it was just linking me to "unanswered", but there's a ton more. I have better things to do than manually removing something that should have been done automatically by a mod, I give up, ignore reality and reason and keep it.

disclaimer: in past I have already been in favor of deleting this tag, but for entirely different reasons

Arguments in favor of removing it:

As a tag, it's pretty vague. It's sort of like tagging your questions with 'not-bitcoin'.
If it's supposed to go on all non-bitcoin questions, then that's not being done right now.

Argument against: Some questions, like this one are actually about alternative blockchains in general. In that context, it doesn't really make sense to remove the tag.
My opinion: Remove the tag on questions that have a more specific tag. However, when someone wants to ask about bitcoin alternatives in general, leave the 'alternatives' tag.
For example: If I'm asking about how Litecoin's hashing algorithm works, then that shouldn't be tagged alternatives. However, if I'm asking for an overview of different proof-of-work schemes used by alternate blockchains, then that ought to be tagged alternatives or alternative-blockchains

That would be ideal, but it will be a pain to enforce. Still better than the current situation.

Done it manually.
